# Simplification of a Combinatoric problem (n k)^2

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How do I simplify the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}
^2?$$
I have tried, but the best I did was 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{n!n!}{k!k!(n-k)!(n-k)!}}.$$

Comment: Have you tried evaluating this numerically? For $n=1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ say?

Comment: see: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C6%2C20%2C70%2C252&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a trick that reduces it. First we can say that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2 = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}{n\choose n-k}$$

Now let's think about what this means. ${n\choose k}{n\choose n-k}$ is the number of ways to pick $k$ things from a group of $n$, and then pick $n-k$ things from another group of $n$. So if we have a group of $2n$ things that we split it two, it is the number of ways to pick $k$ things from the first group and $n-k$ things from the second group. The crucial observation is that summing this over all k gives the total number of ways to pick $n$ things from the whole group! So the answer is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$$